# Choosing node.js install from Conda environment in VSCode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have been working with Conda without any problem with its virtual environments and VSCode, in python. I have decided to install node.js also with Conda in this environment, so that I could have a fully isolated environment for each project with its own installs for my frontend and backend.

Although working with virtual environments in python did not give me any problem, I am not able to work with this kind of "virtual node.js". The problem is related to plugins. Anybody knows how could I configure VSCode so that plugins work with this installation instead of the global SO install?

I would like to uninstall node from my SO to be able to manage everything with Conda environments.

Answer (score 0):

On **Ubuntu** it works if you first install everything into the conda environment, and then start VS code from the command line.

For example, suppose you have a VS Code extension that depends on python, node.js, git and truffle, you could do the following:

```sh
# create a conda environment with python & node
conda create --name my_env python=3.9
conda activate my_env

# install yarn, which also installs node & npm
conda install -c conda-forge yarn

# install git
conda install git

# install truffle, which is an node.js package
# install with -g flag, which means global, 
#    but since we are in a conda environment
#    it is global to that conda environment
npm install -g truffle

# verify that everything is isolated inside the conda environment
which yarn
which npm
which node
which git
which truffle  # /home/.../miniconda3/envs/my_env/bin/truffle

# Start VS Code from the command line
# To open current folder, use '.'
code .

# Then, inside VS Code, you can install & work with the extension
# and if you look in the output of commands, you can see it
# picks up the proper commands
```

I have not been able to get this approach to work on a **mac**. Somehow it does not pick up the conda environment and I have not yet found a way to make VS Code aware of the conda environment.